# Multiple tables css first child

Tags: css

I am having an issue stylizing a class in the first table while keeping the rest of the tables the same. Let me show an example

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="a"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="a"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="a"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I want the class a of the first table to be different than the rest of the tables. How do I go about doing that?

Thank you for your time.

Edit:

I forgot to mention. I cannot add separate classes on each table. I can only give them all the same class. It is generated that way.

Comment: You could use an id =] css: `#firsttable{/*style*/}` html: `<tr class="a" id="firsttable"></tr>`

Comment: It is not clear what “the first table” means. From the comments, it seems obvious that the real question is quite different from what is written in the question.

Comment: I did not realize how it worked so my apologies if the question was supposed to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer browser you can use CSS3's nth-child():

```
table:nth-child(1) tr.a{
  background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

This works if this is the 1st child of the parent element (e.g. say that these 3 tables are the children of the body.

You can be also more specific that this is the nth `table` element using the `:nth-of-type()` selector.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work. http://dev.dog-company.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5047 This is an example but the code might be too messy.

Comment: which elements/class are you trying to apply to on that site?

Comment: The one in red dashed lines. The added line from your code would be line 761 in the stylesheet. Basically the first table should have no top border. The rest should have top and bottom borders.

Comment: in your case the tables with that class are not the only tables... e.g your first table with the class is like the 3rd table. e.g. this CSS will mark the row as pink. 
table.madmanSucksTopBorder:nth-child(3) .madmanSucksBottomBorder {
    background: #ffaacc;
}

Comment: The `:first-child` selector is simpler and better supported than `:nth-child(1)`. But this answer is not correct anyway; it does not address the question asked.

Comment: It is inappropriate to accept an answer that clearly does not address the question (and comments say this). You should accept an answer only if *the answer itself* (ignoring the comments) solves the problem *you presented in the question* (as opposite to something completely different discussed in comments).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you're right the question posted appears to be a simplified version of the problem the OP was trying to solve. Usually this makes it easier for others to grasp the issue and help provide a solution. However the root problem was how to select the `nth` something in the DOM to style it differently.  Although my posted answer does work for the supplied question upon investigation of the live site it was apparent that a tweaked version was needed for his/her specific scenario. That solution was also provided and the problem was solved.